# Help required in recognizing plant

Tags: identification, annuals

Purchased this plant yesterday but dont know the name of this plant.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's Jacobea maritima (previously named Senecio/Cineraria), common names include Dusty Miller. It is often grown as an annual plant as part of a summer display, but is actually a tender perennial outdoors. Depending on your temperatures during winter, it may behave as a perennial. Does well in part shade as well as sun http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=a608